# Django: limit_choices_to with with a "through" intermediate table

Tags: django, forms

> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/:
>   "limit_choices_to has no effect when used on a ManyToManyField with a custom intermediate table specified using the through parameter."

Why?! And what to do if I need both `through` and `limit_choices_to`?

Should I fall back from `ModelForm` to simple `Form` in this situation and do it all manually? Or is there a way to do it with `ModelForm`?

Answer (score 2):

I tested `limit_choices_to` with a `through` `ManyToManyField`. **And surprisingly it works**, despite the docs say it doesn't.

Still, if it's not working for you, you can set a custom queryset for the `ManyToMany` field in your `ModelForm`.

```
# models
class YourModel(models.Model):
    some_attr = models.BooleanField()

class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_field = models.ManyToManyField(YourModel, through=...)


# forms
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    my_field = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=YourModel.objects.filter(some_attr=True))
```

Comment: Bang on. Keep in mind that if you use `limit_choices_to` on the fields with the `manyTomany` intermediate table it works a trick. Django FTW.